# ISS Induced Spin during Altitude Correction Boost

Tags: iss

Since the entire structure of ISS is not perfectly symmetrical and that the thrust vector produced during firing up of Soyuz thrusters/engines during altitude correction, is not perfectly aligned with the centre of mass of ISS, does such manuevers induce a slight spin to the station, which might be later corrected by attitude stabilising thruster?

Comment: What is Earth's Terminator? Is it kind of a fixed point?

Comment: The astronauts keep the crosshairs centered on the Earth's terminator visually; one controlling pitch while the other controls yaw, while a third astronaut counts to 39 seconds. (humor!) https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJ1sq.gif

Comment: This is quite an interesting question by the way, I'm looking forward to a serious answer.

Answer (score 6):

ISS reboosts are typically done by Progress logistics resupply vehicles, not Soyuzes.

The Progress provides three-axis control during the reboost burn by firing its attitude control thrusters.  There are no significant residual rotational rates after a properly executed reboost.

> The  Service  Module  provides  control  in  all  three  axes 
>   (although  its  roll  control  is  not  particularly  efficient), 
>   and  a   Progress  or  an  ATV  at  the  SM
>   -Aft docking port can provide control in all three axes as well.

Although no further flights of the European ATV are planned to the ISS, the referenced paper gives an idea of the relative magnitude of propellant used during reboost for altitude raising vs. attitude control.

> Three  ATV  vehicles  -  Jules  Verne  (2008),  Johannes  Kepler  (2011)  and  Edoardo  Amaldi  (2012)  –   together  performed  a  total  of  25  maneuvers 
>   to  provide  67  m/s  of  ISS  reboost  at  an  expense  of  8400  kg 
>   of  propellants.   Attitude control propellants  during   these
>   reboost maneuvers accounted for an additional 1926 kg.

Source "[On
-Orbit Propulsion System Performance of ISS Visiting 
Vehicles](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/20130013168.pdf)"

Answer (score 3):

> Do such manuevers induce a slight spin to the station, which might be later corrected by attitude stabilising thruster?

This is not done after the fact. It is done while the spacecraft is firing its thrusters.

Any spacecraft, not just the ISS, is subject to cross coupling where thrusters fired to produce a desired force also result in an undesired torque. Cross coupling where thrusters fired to produce a desired torque also result in an undesired force also occurs.

The ability of the spacecraft to counteract these undesired torques and forces while the thrusters are active is one of the key aspects investigated during the design phase of the spacecraft. The spacecraft control system must be able to counteract these undesired rotational and linear accelerations at all times.